# How to access a JMX Mbean from a tomcat website?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I have a web service that exposes an mbean. I am able to view that mbean using jconsole. Now I need that function exposed on a new tomcat website.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation?? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.jolokia.org/ and http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html